# Regex for balanced and unbalanced strings

Tags: regex, matching, balancing-groups

I need to match strings that can be between parentheses `{}`. The string can also contain more types of parentheses. It can be balanced and unbalanced, too.

For example: `{Title} {Size{()} {Color({[]})} {Test{}  {Color{}}`

So, I need to remove actually the strings between the `{....}`

In this case the matched strings should be: `Title, Size{(), Color({[]}), Test{, Color{}`

I'm using this regex

```
Regex regex =  new Regex("\\{([^}]+)}");
```

I'm using then:

```
regex.Matches(checkedString), where checkedString could be: ( {Title} {Size{()} {Color({[]})} {Test{}  {Color{}})
```

It works only when the parenthesis is not closed, so it works well for: `{Size{()}` - it gets the Size{() string.
it does not work well for `{Color{}}` , so where the parenthesis are balanced. In this case I should get `Color{}`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like ,NET, try `var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<!\S)\{(\S*?)}(?!\S)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToList();`. I assume all your matches are between whitespaces or start/end of string and have no whitespace in them.

Comment: It'd help if you had better definition of what is "valid" for you. For example - ares paces meaningful (`{Test{}{Color{}}`, `{  Color( {[]  } )}`)? Where can words be (`{Size{If(x)M}`)? How many levels of braces can you have (`{Color{{Color{}}}`)? In general, it is difficult to match non-balanced string in a way that isn't ambiguous, so it's easier if the rules are cleared, or if this format has a spec or a name (looks like a templating language?).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew- thanks, it works perfectly